# Android- JSON object

Tags: php, android, json

The php server contain this

```
$test_array = array(
    'array1' => array(
            'field1'=>'1',
            'field2'=>'2'),
    'array2'=>array(
            array('field3'=>'3', 'field4'=>'4', 'field4'=>'5')
    )
```

);

How can I use the JOSN object in android to fill the" test_array"?

Comment: make a post request to your php server and fill it.

Comment: This is the problem how to fill it, Do you have a sample code?

Comment: What do you mean by `to fill the" test_array"`? Do you want to send data from the android device to the server/php-script or the other way round?

Comment: Yes, I want to send data to the server

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to return this response:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($test_array);
```

In an Android application after receiving response:

```
yourJSONOBject.put("new_key", "new_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a jsonobject in android

```
JSONObject a  = new JSONObject("{hello1: hi, hello2: hey}");
params= a.toString()
```

make a get request to php server
 look here  : http://veerasundar.com/blog/2011/09/making-get-and-post-requests-in-android-application/

and then in php parse the param as json

```
json_decode($_GET['param'])
```

Comment: How to send the array using JOSN ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is snippet from my code, parsing depends on our json structure

```
try {
 URL url = new URL("http://www.domain.com/data.json");
 InputStream input  = url.openStream();

 BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
 StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
 String line;

 while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
  total.append(line);
 }

 JSONArray jsonReply = new JSONArray(total.toString());

 for (int i = 0; i < jsonReply.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject jObject = jsonReply.getJSONObject(i);
 }

 } catch (Exception e) {
}
```